# How does using an inboud NAT help in terms of security?

Tags: security, azure, load-balancing, rdp, azure-networking

When creating a VM, I didn't give it a public ip address to RDP into it since that won't be secure. I made a public load balancer and added the VM to the backend pool and created an inbound nat rule with the VM as the target using port 3389.

How does using an Inbound NAT in Load balancer help in terms of security?, since it would forward all RDP's to our VM anyway making it feel as if the public ip of the load balancer is the public ip of the VM itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does using an Inbound NAT in Load balancer help in terms of security?, since it would forward all RDP's to our VM anyway making it feel as if the public ip of the load balancer is the public ip of the VM itself?

It doesn't. NAT is *not* about security; it's about network addressing.

For filtering traffic, we have firewalls.